# Can pandas findall() return a str instead of list?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe containing a lot of variables:

```
df.columns
Out[0]: 
Index(['COUNADU_SOIL_P_NUMBER_16_DA_B_VE_count_nr_lesion_PRATZE',
       'COUNEGG_SOIL_P_NUMBER_50_DA_B_VT_count_nr_lesion_PRATZE',
       'COUNJUV_SOIL_P_NUMBER_128_DA_B_V6_count_nr_lesion_PRATZE',
       'COUNADU_SOIL_P_SAUDPC_150_DA_B_V6_lesion_saudpc_PRATZE',
       'CONTRO_SOIL_P_pUNCK_150_DA_B_V6_lesion_p_control_PRATZE',
       'COUNJUV_SOIL_P_p_0_100_16_DA_B_V6_lesion_incidence_PRATZE',
       'COUNADU_SOIL_P_p_0_100_50_DA_B_VT_lesion_incidence_PRATZE',
       'COUNEGG_SOIL_P_p_0_100_128_DA_B_VT_lesion_incidence_PRATZE',
       'COUNEGG_SOIL_P_NUMBER_50_DA_B_V6_count_nr_spiral_HELYSP',
       'COUNJUV_SOIL_P_NUMBER_128_DA_B_V10_count_nr_spiral_HELYSP', # and so on
```

I would like to keep only the number followed by DA, so the first column is `16_DA`. I have been using the pandas function `findall()`:

```
df.columns.str.findall(r'[0-9]*\_DA')
Out[595]: 
Index([ ['16_DA'],  ['50_DA'], ['128_DA'], ['150_DA'], ['150_DA'],
        ['16_DA'],  ['50_DA'], ['128_DA'],  ['50_DA'], ['128_DA'], ['150_DA'],
        ['150_DA'],  ['50_DA'], ['128_DA'],
```

But this returns a list, which i would like to avoid, so that i end up with a column index looking like this:

```
df.columns
Out[595]: 
Index('16_DA',  '50_DA', '128_DA', '150_DA', '150_DA',
      '16_DA',  '50_DA', '128_DA',  '50_DA', '128_DA', '150_DA',
```

Is there a smoother way to do this?

Comment: What do you want your output to look like? Do you just want only ther first value? Or do you need the list converted to a string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.str.join(", ")` to join all found matches with a comma and space:

```py
df.columns.str.findall(r'\d+_DA').str.join(", ")
```

Or, just use `str.extract` to get the first match:

```py
df.columns.str.extract(r'(\d+_DA)', expand=False)
```

Comment: df.columns.str.extract(r'(\d+_DA)', expand=False) and df.columns.str.findall(r'\d+_DA').str.join(", ") works perfectly

Answer (score 3):

```
from typing import List


pattern = r'[0-9]*\_DA'
flattened: List[str] = sum(df.columns.str.findall(pattern), [])
output: str = ",".join(flattened)
```